# Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded error

Tags: php, timeout

I'm getting the following error message:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://localhost/sample_pie.php) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\EXACT\report.php on line 206
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\EXACT\report.php on line 206

Here is the line 206:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/sample_pie.php';
$img = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\piechart.jpg';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

What do I have to do to fix this?

Comment: You need to accept answers to your questions, or people will not answer your questions anymore. BTW: Which of the three lines is line number 206??

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Your script executed for more then 60 seconds and was terminated. There is a value in php.ini defining maximum time PHP script can run. The purpose of this is to prevent scripts from hanging. You could try to optimize your script but if it's intended to run for so long you can just update the value (it's called `max_execution_time`).

You can also try changing this value for particular script by running set_time_limit() function, [docs here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Answer (score 28):

max_input_time can also cause the same error.

Comment: thanks, this work for me max_input_time=3600  or 1 hour :)

Comment: Thanks :) The error message "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded error" is not so clear when it's caused by max_input_time...

Answer (score 2):

Just increase the `max_execution_time`  in `php.ini.` Set it to `1800` and restart your apache or any other server you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that PHP is not able to open http://localhost/sample_pie.php to read the contents of the file. See if you are able to open the http://localhost/sample_pie.php file in browser.

Also is the page very large?

Answer (score 0):

It means PHP was unable to access the resource `http://localhost/sample_pie.php`, and thus the operation timed out. Try to access it through the browser.

Answer (score -12):

I was using ffmpeg and there is video uploading and ffmpeg copies some files on temp and my anti virus program blocks that copying and there is Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

I REMOVED ANTİVİRUS PROGRAM I SAW PROBLEM GONE OFF