# PHP Fatal Error: Maximum execution time exceeded

Tags: php, mysql

I have this problem: this script checks the pagerank of a certain list on links. When I insert ~150 links it works perfectly but if I put a great number of links it shows me the following error:

[image]

This is the code:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    function StrToNum($Str, $Check, $Magic)
    {
        $Int32Unit = 4294967296;  // 2^32

        $length = strlen($Str);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $Check *= $Magic;     
            if ($Check >= $Int32Unit) {
                $Check = ($Check - $Int32Unit * (int) ($Check / $Int32Unit));

                $Check = ($Check < -2147483648) ? ($Check + $Int32Unit) : $Check;
            }
            $Check += ord($Str{$i}); 
        }
        return $Check;
    }
    function CheckHash($Hashnum)
    {
        $CheckByte = 0;
        $Flag = 0;

        $HashStr = sprintf('%u', $Hashnum) ;
        $length = strlen($HashStr);

        for ($i = $length - 1;  $i >= 0;  $i --) {
            $Re = $HashStr{$i};
            if (1 === ($Flag % 2)) {              
                $Re += $Re;     
                $Re = (int)($Re / 10) + ($Re % 10);
            }
            $CheckByte += $Re;
            $Flag ++;    
        }

        $CheckByte %= 10;
        if (0 !== $CheckByte) {
            $CheckByte = 10 - $CheckByte;
            if (1 === ($Flag % 2) ) {
                if (1 === ($CheckByte % 2)) {
                    $CheckByte += 9;
                }
                $CheckByte >>= 1;
            }
        }

        return '7'.$CheckByte.$HashStr;
    }
    function HashURL($String)
    {
        $Check1 = StrToNum($String, 0x1505, 0x21);
        $Check2 = StrToNum($String, 0, 0x1003F);

        $Check1 >>= 2;     
        $Check1 = (($Check1 >> 4) & 0x3FFFFC0 ) | ($Check1 & 0x3F);
        $Check1 = (($Check1 >> 4) & 0x3FFC00 ) | ($Check1 & 0x3FF);
        $Check1 = (($Check1 >> 4) & 0x3C000 ) | ($Check1 & 0x3FFF);    

        $T1 = (((($Check1 & 0x3C0) << 4) | ($Check1 & 0x3C)) <<2 ) | ($Check2 & 0xF0F );
        $T2 = (((($Check1 & 0xFFFFC000) << 4) | ($Check1 & 0x3C00)) << 0xA) | ($Check2 & 0xF0F0000 );

        return ($T1 | $T2);
    }
    function getpagerank($url) {
        $query="http://toolbarqueries.google.com/tbr?client=navclient-auto&ch=".CheckHash(HashURL($url)). "&features=Rank&q=info:".$url;
        $data=file_get_contents($query);
        $pos = strpos($data, "Rank_");
        if($pos === false){} else{
            $pagerank = substr($data, $pos + 9);
            return $pagerank;
        }


    }
    if($_POST['urls'])
    {
        ?><table border="1">
        <th>URL</th>
        <th>Pagerank</th>
        <?
        $urls=trim($_POST['urls']);
        $url=explode("\n",$urls);
        foreach($url as $url)
        {
            if($url)
            {
                $url=trim($url);
                $pagerank=getpagerank($url);
                ?>
                <tr><td><?php echo $url; ?></td><td><?php echo $pagerank; ?></td></tr>
                <?        
                flush();
            }                
        }
        ?></table><?
    }
    else
    {
        ?><form action="" method="post">
        URLS:<br /><textarea name="urls" cols="50" rows="10">http://www.google.com
    http://www.yahootracer.com</textarea><br /><input type="submit" value="Check PR"/>
        </form>
        <?
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to optimize the code, or do you just want it to run, regardless of length?  If it's the latter, you can adjust your timeout in your configuration.

Comment: Try putting `set_time_limit(0);` at the beginning of the script and see if that solves the problem. You can also edit your php.ini to have the same effect: http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php

Comment: Lots of questions about PHP max execution time on SO. Check for instance the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420249/maximum-execution-time-of-60-seconds-exceeded-error?rq=1.

Comment: A good approach if it is just a processing script is to run it from command line, then you won't encounter that issue again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have reached the default script execution timeout. You could try use `set_time_limit(0)` to disable the timeout. But as probably you are running your script under webserver - then the webserver timeouts can apply, which cannot be avoided and are configured by system administrators. In this case - best thing would be to perform huge inserts by running a shell script (e.g. cronjob).

Comment: Still a better answer in my opinion. At least I can do is upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

You must add `set_time_limit(0)` after the row 
`$query="http://toolbarqueries.google.com/tbr?client=navclient-auto&ch=".CheckHash(HashURL($url)). "&features=Rank&q=info:".$url;`

Comment: why there and not globally in the first lines of the file? Any particular reason?

Comment: It is preferred to put `set_time_limit` at the beginning of the script for several reasons most notably readability and the way `set_time_limit` works. You see every time you call `set_time_limit` you are actually resetting an internal timer and if the lines preceding it take a long time to execute you might come into situation where `set_time_limit` will never be executed. That's why it should be right at the beginning of the script.