# Html::style time out

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

everyone.

I use laravel6 (v6.18.2), and run `php artisan serve`.

I visit this page, then it display `Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded`

Here is my code :

```
<head>
  <!-- something -->

  <!-- plugin css -->
{{--  {!! Html::style('assets/plugins/@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css') !!}--}}
  <link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  {!! Html::style('assets/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css') !!}
  <!-- end plugin css -->
</head>
```

I commented out this line of code `{!! Html::style('assets/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css') !!}`， then it runs normally. so i am sure "Html::style" cause the crash of the page.

and sometime it display `Class 'Html' not found (View: C:\Users\L\Desktop\xx\resources\views\layouts\panel\master-mini.blade.php)`

Could anyone please tell me why?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Please check this answer, I think it can solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1420263/13066106

Comment: In fact, there is no code that makes this this page run for about 1 minute. There must be an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you start commenting code in the structure of the Blade file, and update to see which code snippet is the one that makes your page take so long to load. This is how I check for these kinds of errors.

Comment: I commented out this line of code `{!! Html::style('assets/plugins/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css') !!}`， then it runs normally. so i am sure "Html::style" cause the crash of the page.

Comment: hum... Could it be that that ```perfect-scrollbar.css``` file ... is trying to get a file from a URL of an online server .. could you check it from the browser console? ... maybe that's why it takes so long .. anyway .. because don't use the following syntax..just to check ..```<link href="{{ asset('plugins/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">```

Comment: Unbelievable, but it works.  Thank you for your answer sincerely.

Comment: Sorry, i use this community firstly, and forgot to accept your answer.